# Sending formatted/html Outlook email with Ruby Win32ole

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, outlook, win32ole

Is it possible to send formatted email, whether html or otherwise with Ruby's WIN32OLE - I have been able to send a plain text email through automation (as follows), but was hoping to be able to add some formatting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
require 'win32ole'

@outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
email = @outlook.CreateItem(0)
email.Subject = 'Test Subject'
email.Body = 'Test Body'
email.To = 'recipient@example.com'
email.Save
email.Send
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to use HTMLBody instead of Body as in:

```
email.HTMLBody = '<h3>Test body in HTML format</h3>'
```